# Where is my (algebra) mistake? Converting parametric to Cartesian equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, parametric, plane-curves

I'm having a problem with my solution to a textbook exercise:

**Find the Cartesian equation of the curve given by this parametric equation:**
$$x = \frac{t}{2t-1}, y = \frac{t}{t+1}$$

The textbook's answer is $y = \frac{x}{3x-1}$

My solution is different. I understand how the textbook got to its solution, but I can't find where I made my mistake. Can anyone spot my error below?

$$x = \frac{t}{2t-1} = \frac{t}{2t} - \frac{t}{1}$$
$$\implies x = \frac{1}{2} - t$$
$$\implies x - \frac{1}{2} = -t$$
$$\implies t = -x + \frac{1}{2}$$

Sub this into $y = \frac{t}{t+1} \implies y = \frac{-x + \frac{1}{2}}{-x + \frac{1}{2} + 1}$
$$= \frac{-x + \frac{1}{2}}{-x + \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{-x + \frac{1}{2}}{1}$$
$$= 1 - x + \frac{1}{2}$$
$$= -x + \frac{3}{2}$$

So $y = -x + \frac{3}{2}$

---

I suspect my error is when I split my fractions up, but if so, why can't I do it like that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Also, is my use of the implication symbol acceptable as written above? Thanks!

Comment: $$x = \frac{t}{2t-1} = \frac{t}{2t} - \frac{t}{1}$$, really?

Comment: Yeah... $x = \frac{t}{2t-1} \neq \frac{t}{2t} - \frac{t}{1}$. There's your error.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I understand now. Would either of you like to post as an answer so I can accept? If not I'll self-answer.

Comment: @Raskolnikov got here first so let him get the checkmark :)

Comment: I don't know where to start explaining. This is a common mistake, a bit like the freshman's dream. To expunge this one from the world will take a good pedagogue and I have to fly!

Comment: @Raskolnikov I'm sure you just have to ctrl-c+ctrl-v your answer, dude :)

Comment: Just to clarify, I had mistakenly thought $\frac{a}{b+c} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c}$. I was confusing it with the rule $\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c}$ (which I hope is true!)

Comment: Danny: you made the mistake of splitting the denominator twice in your derivation: be sure to avoid it by remembering some examples, e.g.: $0.5 = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+1} \neq \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} = 2$. Your second rule in the last comment is perfectly ok. Moreover, your use of the implication symbol looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks Theo, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said Danny,

$$\frac{a}{b+c} \neq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c}$$

and Theo pointed out with a simple example why:

$$0.5 = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+1} \neq \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} = 2 \; .$$

It is a common mistake however, so tempting that few people have resisted making it.

P.S: Note you made the mistake twice, once in the formula with $x$ and once in the one with $y$.

Answer (score 0):

It's been so long that this answer will probably be irrelevant, but for what it's worth here's how I'd have done it:

$x = \frac{t}{2t-1} \Rightarrow 2tx-x=t \Rightarrow 2tx-t=x \Rightarrow t = \frac{x}{2x-1}$

$y = \frac{t}{t+1} \Rightarrow ty+y=t \Rightarrow ty-t=-y \Rightarrow t= \frac{-y}{y-1}$

Set both equations equal to each other:

$\frac{x}{2x-1} = \frac{-y}{y-1} \Rightarrow \frac{xy}{2x-1}-\frac{x}{2x-1} = -y$

$\Rightarrow \frac{xy}{2x-1}+y = \frac{x}{2x-1} \Rightarrow y(\frac{x}{2x-1}+1) = y\frac{3x-1}{2x-1} = \frac{x}{2x-1} \Rightarrow y = \frac{x(2x-1)}{(3x-1)(2x-1)} = \frac{x}{3x-1}$

No muss, no fuss! Though your way is certainly shorter.